How to implement class weight sampling in multi label classification?
I am working on a multi label classification problem and need some guidance on computing class weights using Scikit-Learn.
Problem Context:
I have a dataset with 9973 training samples.The labels are one-hot encoded, representing 13 different classes.The shape of my training labels is (9973, 13).
I want to use this code:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight

y_integers = np.argmax(y, axis=1)
class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y_integers), y_integers)
d_class_weights = dict(enumerate(class_weights))

This does not work says, too may positional arguments. My training samples look like this:
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

How can i implement in multi class classification problem so that my dataset imbalance can be solved ?
Edit 1: It is working fine now, Do you think it works in multilabel because I read somewhere, that you must use sampling weight instead of class weight. How can i implement that ?

You need to call compute_class_weights with keyword arguments rather than positional, just like they do in the documentation:
compute_class_weight('balanced', classes=np.unique(y_integers), y=y_integers)

The way to know this is by looking at the function signature when they define it (also seen in the documentation I linked above):
def compute_class_weight(class_weight, *, classes, y)

The asterisk * means that positional arguments after the first one (class_weight) are disregarded. It's a common method to force users to use keyword/named arguments like classes= or y=. See this Stackoverflow answer.

Ok, Moreover, is there any thing need to change because it is multilabel and I was getting confused why are we converting it into integers etc. Is there anything else to change. Lastly, simple i pass this model.fit ?

That's a whole separate question. You have not provided any information like the original values of y, what kind of model you're trying to fit, or anything. I would recommend you accept and close this question if your error was fixed, and open a new thread with all this information. But, as a quick answer: For most models in sklearn, you should be able to skip this all entirely and pass class_weight='balanced' directly when you initialise your model. E.g., model = DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced').

There are more details on how to specify class weights in a multilabel case in the documentation for the model you're using. For example, in DecisionTreeClassifier it specifies: "for multioutput (including multilabel) weights should be defined for each class of every column in its own dict. For example, for four-class multilabel classification weights should be [{0: 1, 1: 1}, {0: 1, 1: 5}, {0: 1, 1: 1}, {0: 1, 1: 1}] instead of [{1:1}, {2:5}, {3:1}, {4:1}]."
